# Создать таблицы в БД, используя XSD схему

Tags: xml, c#, sql-server, xsd, база-данных

Есть приложение на C#, в котором обрабатываются данные из xml. Есть xml и соответствующая ей xsd схема. Возможно ли автоматически создать БД (ms sql 2008 либо ms sql compact) с таблицей для хранения информации из xml и загрузить туда данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу возникает мысль [десериализовать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) XML в объект.
Затем с помощью рефлексии пробежаться по всем свойствам объекта и сгенерировать скрипт sql

```
        var student = new Student();
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in student.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
           Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
           Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
        }
```

На основе свойств несложно выбрать необходимый тип данных в бд и [создать скрипт](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp).

Вот наскоро набросанный extension метод для генерации скрипта:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

namespace DynamicCreteTable
{
    public static  class ExtensionCreateScript
    {
        public static string CreateTableScript(this object obj )
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append("CREATE TABLE ");
            builder.Append(obj.GetType().Name);
            builder.Append("(");

            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {

                builder.Append(propertyInfo.Name);
                builder.Append(" ");
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType==typeof(Int32))
                {
                    builder.Append("int, ");
                }
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType==typeof(string))
                {
                    builder.Append("varchar(255), ");
                }
            }
            builder.Remove(builder.Length - 2, 2);
            builder.Append(");");
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А для чего тогда нужна xsd схема?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009154/how-to-create-sql-server-table-schema-from-a-xml-schema-with-net-and-visual-s вот предлагают использовать готовый софт

Comment: как я понимаю, данная утилита не работает с sql compact